# Is there an API for adding/editing posts and viewing inbox in the works?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, api

I'd really like a full blown android-client for Stack Exchange, and I don't mind making one myself, however there are a lack of APIs available for adding, editing, voting and such, and checking if the currently logged in user has permission to add/edit/vote. All in all there is a lack of API where a user can log in at all, which I find kind of frustrating, so I was just wondering (and I'm not even sure I'm asking at the right place) if there is any work in progress to create a more full-blown API for the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is currently read-only.  But rest assured you are not the only person pushing for a full API.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen, I was just wondering if there was any non-readonly api in the works or not.

Comment: @Alxandr: You and the rest of SO...

Comment: lol, that so, so don't devs like hang out around here and chill, answering these kinds of questions? :-P

Comment: @Alxandr yep. The SO team are: http://stackoverflow.com/about/team from which you should be able to find SO/Meta profiles. Jeff Atwood is the top user by rep of MSO and he's the CTO, so yes, they do.

Comment: @Alxandr: They typically do but don't count on it.  If you're lucky, you might get an official response in a day or two.  The Dev team is really small compared to the user base so it takes a lot longer to get a response when only the SO team can answer.